# Meta Box - Javascript Datatable

Tags: metabox, javascript, save-post

Hello my fellow WP Developers,

I am running into a wall with a custom theme I am creating for a personal project.

> Background

It's a website that will be used by users that collect a specific type of figures. This site will basically be a big data dump of all the figures ever released in this line.
And because these figures are so rare to find I wanted to make a site where collectors can compile their own "I own this" list and what the current second hand value of the figure is and if there currently is a store that sells the figure.

> Current Challenge

What I am trying to accomplish right now is the following:

I have added a custom post type for the figures (Called 'wdcc').
This post type has 3 taxonomies

- Series
- Edition
- Store

What I currently want is that I can add "Stores" through normal means (add new etc.). Now I've created a custom meta box which I want to use to add stores that currently sell the figure. So I can choose the store from a dropdown (The select is populated with a foreach loop) and input the selling price in a input field.
My idea was to use Datatable scripts and currently implemented this one [Datatables.](https://www.datatables.net/)

> Problem

I got the meta box semi working. There are still some parts that not entirely work as I want them too but I can interact with the meta box.
It's more that I can't seem to figure out how to save the meta data I added through jQuery/Javascript.

I've been browsing through the codex like crazy at functions like `save_post` and `update_post_meta`.
Searched google for hints and tips but so far I can't seem to figure this out.

> Code

I use X Theme as my parent theme and have x-child as the active theme.
I basically use their code style and some functions as they do and edit, add, update where needed.

[I think it's best if I gist these files so here is a link to (what I believe) are the 3 most relevant files](https://gist.github.com/Shuyinsama/1feca8348a0d2d6d23d8)

> Extra

If more info is needed. Please feel free to ask.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Creating a new PostBox in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211793/84219). As long as you name the fields the same in render as you do in save then you're good.

**RENDER**

```
echo '<input type="text" id="boxpost_meta_field" name="boxpost_meta_field"';
```

**SAVE**

```
$mydata = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['boxpost_meta_field'] );

// Update the meta field.
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_boxpost_meta_field_value_key', $mydata );
```

**GET**

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_boxpost_meta_field_value_key', true );
```